# What is the difference between "group.execute" and "group.move"?

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*I LOVE ROS*

Hi, I have two options to move my robot with MoveIt:

Option 1

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;
kPyGlobals.move_group_end->setJointValueTarget( goals );
kPyGlobals.move_group_end->plan( plan );
kPyGlobals.move_group_end->execute( plan );
```

Option 2

```
kPyGlobals.move_group_end->setJointValueTarget( goals );
if ( syn == Synctype::SYNC )
    kPyGlobals.move_group_end->move();
else if ( syn == Synctype::ASYNC )
    kPyGlobals.move_group_end->asyncMove();
```

Normally I use option 1 because I want to use the created plan for later.

But what is the difference between these two options?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386530/what-is-the-difference-between-%22group.execute%22-and-%22group.move%22?/) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-09-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-09-15**:
I am glad that you love ROS. What is your question?

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-09-15**:
what is the difference between these two options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you noticed, using `plan` and `execute` rather than only `move`, you can inspect, store and change the planning result. For example, you could:

- plan a motion ahead of time and execute it later
- store a series of motions that end at the start position and execute them repeatedly without replanning
- retime your resulting trajectory(ies)

With `plan`, you can also use `setStartState` to plan motions that do not begin at the current state of the robot. This is not possible with `move`.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on 2021-09-15**:
thank you so much